# Why are C# closures implemented using classes instead of accessing the stack frame of their parents?

Tags: c#, clr

It is well-known that C# implements closures by capturing the local variables of the parent methods into a class which contains the lambda / anonymous method, and these variables it is accessing.

An alternative approach, taken by Pascal, is by passing the address of the stack frame of the parent (actually, the addresses of the stack frames of all parents) to the nested / anonymous function ([link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20231204-00/?p=109095)).

The second approach is very likely more efficient in terms of performance ([link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-local-functions-in-c-7/)).  There is no need for allocations and load on GC, and it might be even more cache-friendly due to the native locality of the stack.  The performance impact of closures is recognized by Microsoft and lead to (static anonymous functions)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/static-anonymous-functions].

My question is: why did C# / CLR designers opted for capturing local variables using a class instead of just passing the stack frames of their parents?  Accessing parent's stack is not a problem: `ref` parameters are a clear example that is it allowed, and possible.

Comment: _"why did C# / CLR designers"_ - unless someone finds a resource where one of them explains their reasoning, there would be no other way to answer this question than _being_ one of them and write the answer. Not sure if one of them is among the users of this site, though.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585

Comment: Don't assume that, in fact, roslyn is much smarter than you imagine, it also uses stack values for the example in the first link: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBBmABM3AYVwG9NcLdYAXXAeQFdqBTAJwAobcYBKcyshkrCqMWlFwBeXAAYA3Jn4j8AFlwBJGDDacxuMHyHLSS4xQRqAsgHtWzTdo6GzwkmdMvKEgNTSwCo08AXyUPYxs7Bx0eALMQjEVAkSiOXljjBAB2KnSKeKCgA==

Comment: Delegates can be stored on the heap, just like any other object. If it referred to a stack frame that would not be possible, since the stack frame will have a different lifetime than the delegate. I believe Pascals nested functions follows different rules, with different tradeoffs with regards to performance and usefulness.